# Chrome extensions and third party cookies alternative

Tags: google-chrome-extension, third-party-cookies

On mid-2022 Google plans to disable third party cookies by default.
My use with 3rd party cookies is through google chrome extension (not for ads service)

I use an Iframe to translate some words on the document.

It looks something like this:
[image]

- I have a chrome extension that loads an Iframe (In red)
- The Iframe (in green) is under my domain x.com (i wish)
- Each request that goes from my iframe client to the server is attaching cookie, but from mid-2022 it will be blocked due to chrome policy change and considering that the cookies are 3rd party

I have tried to find solution for this,
All I have found for now is [TheTradeDesk Unified ID 2.0](https://www.thetradedesk.com/us/about-us/industry-initiatives/unified-id-solution-2-0) but it will not help me since it's not store value / jwt (its anonymous id)

But could't find any other solution
Any ideas how to handle this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This is coming to bite me and my yet to be released extension, and I figured I should face the issue upfront.

Answer (score 0):

We're also facing something similar, where we noticed if you have your browser configured to block 3rd party cookies, functionality regarding authentication did not work.

This afternoon, we followed a hunch to try and see if the setting to block 3rd party cookies also has an effect on an extension's background page (we're still using manifest v2). And turns out, it is not. So even with 3rd party cookies being blocked, requests made from the extension's background page can still use them.

Not sure if this is by design or a bug. And we still need to investigate how this works with manifest v3.

But hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A good news is that Google keeps postponing the timeline for removing 3rd party cookies from Chrome. Right now (Dec 2022) it's planned for the second half of 2024 (https://blog.google/products/chrome/update-testing-privacy-sandbox-web/).

Eventually, we'll need a workaround, though. As @schmkr mentioned, Chrome extension's own code (background page / service worker, and iframes sources from the embedded HTML via chrome://... URLs) are not considered 3rd party. So there are two workarounds:

- Pack your iframe app (html/js) as a part of the chrome extension instead of loading it from the external website (x.com in your example).
- Keep the iframe app externally sourced, but change its logic. It should not send XHR/Fetch requests any more. Instead it should ask the extension background page / service worker to do that (using the messaging API).